# The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "MY_LINKED_SERVER" does not contain the table "my_database.my_table"

Tags: mysql, sql-server, odbc, linked-server

On my server I have "Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter 64 bit" and "SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise" and installed "mysql-connector-odbc-5.3.10-winx64.msi".
Using "ODBC Data Source Administrator" created an odbc connection to a remote MySQL database. And created a linked server to that odbc connection in sql server with the name "MY_LINKED_SERVER".
I try to run the following command in management studio :

```
select * from [MY_LINKED_SERVER]...[my_database.my_table]
```

And I get this error:

> Msg 7314, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
> The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "MY_LINKED_SERVER"
>   does not contain the table "my_database.my_table". The table either
>   does not exist or the current user does not have permissions on that
>   table.

FYI everything works fine on my pc with windows 10 and sql server 2017 express edition.

Comment: I know `[my_database.my_table]` is a valid sysname and can be used for a table in SQL Server, but did you perhaps mean to use `[MY_LINKED_SERVER].[my_database]..[my_table]` instead?

Comment: No, [MY_LINKED_SERVER].[my_database]..[my_table] does not work even on my pc.